# How to get array list data using ajax call (pass array list data controller to ajax method)

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

My controller class like that.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/ajaxcallabd"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody// <== this annotation will bind Arr class and convert to json response.
    String addAnotherAppointmenttt(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestBody String userJson, Model model, BindingResult errors) {
        System.out.println("*******88888" + userJson);
        List<stageViiChartData> chartData = stageViiChartDataServices.findBystageViiChaData(userJson);
        return chartData.toString();
    }
```

The above code create the List data. I want to pass above list data using ajax call.

My ajax method like that.

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/MobitelProgressTool/ajaxcallabd",
                    data: userJson,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    // dataType: 'JSON',
                    datatype:'text',
                    success: function (mJSONArray) {
                        alert(mJSONArray);
                    },
                    failure: function (erroes) {
                        alert(erroes + ">>>>>");//handle it in a proper way
                    }
                });
```

But above `mJSONArray` is string type. I want to get Json type. I don't know how I create it.

my chartData array like that.

```
[[stageViiChartDataModal: Updated_Scope = Ericsson, Dependency = WIP, On_Air_date = 4-Dec-15], [stageViiChartDataModal: Updated_Scope = Ericsson, Dependency = WIP, On_Air_date = 9-Dec-15]]
```

Comment: JSON.parse(mJSONArray)

Comment: Why don't you return chartData instead of chartData.toString()

Answer (score 0):

Just do..

```
success: function (mJSONArray) {
   var d = JSON.parse(mJSONArray);
   alert(d);
},
```

Comment: my chartData array like that. [[stageViiChartDataModal: Updated_Scope = Ericsson, Dependency = WIP, On_Air_date = 4-Dec-15], [stageViiChartDataModal: Updated_Scope = Ericsson, Dependency = WIP, On_Air_date = 9-Dec-15]] Therefor console error is
Unexpected token c

Comment: well thats clearly not JSON at all, no idea what youre trying to achieve

Comment: I have chartData object array like that. [[stageViiChartDataModal: Updated_Scope = Ericsson, Dependency = WIP, On_Air_date = 4-Dec-15], [stageViiChartDataModal: Updated_Scope = Ericsson, Dependency = WIP, On_Air_date = 9-Dec-15]]   I want to pass above array using ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Content-Type `Content-Type: application/json`then you can pass json arral list data.

```
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.ignoreAcceptHeader(true).defaultContentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
        configurer.ignoreAcceptHeader(true).defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }
```